# How to create an array of binary digits of given unsigned integer numbers with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of numbers between 0 and 3 and I want to create a 2D array of their binary digits.

in the future may be I need to have array of numbers between 0 and 7 or 0 to 15.

Currently my array is defined like this:

```
a = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I used numpy `unpackbits` function:

```
b = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
```

and the result is this :

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

As you can see it created a 2d array with 8 items in column while I'm looking for 2 columns 2d array.

here is my desired array:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Is this related to data type `uint8` ?

what is your idea?

Comment: Can't you just take a slice of `b`? https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of approaching the problem is to just adapt your `b` to match your desired output via a simple slicing, similarly to what suggested in [@GrzegorzSkibinski answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778437/5218354):

```
import numpy as np


def gen_bits_by_val(values):
    n = int(max(values)).bit_length()
    return np.unpackbits(values, axis=1)[:, -n:].copy()


print(gen_bits_by_val(a))
# [[0 0]
#  [0 1]
#  [1 0]
#  [1 1]]
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a look-up table, similarly to what suggested in [@WarrenWeckesser answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778700/5218354), using the following:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_bits_by_num(n):
    values = np.arange(2 ** n, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 1)
    return np.unpackbits(values, axis=1)[:, -n:].copy()


bits2 = gen_bits_by_num(2)
print(bits2)
# [[0 0]
#  [0 1]
#  [1 0]
#  [1 1]]
```

which allows for all kind of uses thereby indicated, e.g.:

```
bits4 = gen_bits_by_num(4)
print(bits4[[1, 3, 12]])
# [[0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 0 0]]
```

---

## EDIT

Considering [@PaulPanzer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780628/5218354) the line:

```
return np.unpackbits(values, axis=1)[:, -n:]
```

has been replaced with:

```
return np.unpackbits(values, axis=1)[:, -n:].copy()
```

which is more memory efficient.

It could have been replaced with:

```
return np.unpackbits(values << (8 - n), axis=1, count=n)
```

with similar effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count` keyword. It cuts from the right so you also have to shift bits before applying `unpackbits`.

```
b = np.unpackbits(a<<6, axis=1, count=2)
b
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

This produces a "clean" array:

```
b.flags
#  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
#  OWNDATA : True
#  WRITEABLE : True
#  ALIGNED : True
#  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

In contrast, slicing the full 8-column output of `unpackbits` is in a sense a memory leak because the discarded columns will stay in memory as long as the slice lives.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate `b` to keep just the columns since the first column with `1`:

```py
b=b[:, int(np.argwhere(b.max(axis=0)==1)[0]):]
```

Comment: You could also use `int(max(a)).bit_length()` to determine where to cut, which is probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

For such a small number of bits, you can use a lookup table.

For example, here `bits2` is an array with shape (4, 2) that holds the bits of the integers 0, 1, 2, and 3.  Index `bits2` with the values from `a` to get the bits:

```
In [43]: bits2 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])

In [44]: a = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [45]: bits2[a[:, 0]]
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

This works fine for 3 or 4 bits, too:

```
In [46]: bits4 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [
    ...: 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0,
    ...:  1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [47]: bits4
Out[47]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [48]: x = np.array([0, 1, 5, 14, 9, 8, 15])

In [49]: bits4[x]
Out[49]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Sure, but it's always tedious to write one and `np.arange()` + `np.unpackbits()` + slicing is a good way of building one.

Comment: *"... it's always tedious..."* Hmm... tedious?  You do it *once*!

Comment: Call me a weirdo but I prefer `list(range(10))` over `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, even if I have to type the spelled-out version only once... or, using code from this question, I prefer to define `bits4` via `gen_bits_by_num()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779510/5218354) than the way you suggest defining `bits4`.